# MATLAB Syms For Loop

Tags: matlab

A bit of newbie to MATLAB so hoping for some help.

I'm trying to solve for T2a between the range of x = 40 to 150, and output the corresponding result.

```
sig = 5.670*10^-8;
k = 0.7; 
h = 130; 
p = 0.7;
r1 = 1.50;
r2 = r1 + (1/1000);
r3 = r2 + (100/1000);
T1 = -40 + 273.15;
T3 = 35 + 273.15;

A = 4*pi*r1^2;
e1 = 1-p;
e2 = 1;

syms T2a real
for x = [40:150];

   equ2(x) = (T2a-T3)/(((r3-r2)/((4*pi*r2*r3)*k))+(1/((4*pi*(r3^2))*h))) == (A*sig*((x^4)-(T2a^4)))/((1/e1)+(((1-e2)/e2)*(r1/r2)^2));

   y = solve(equ2,T2a);
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this suits your application requirements but this method uses the `vpasolve()` function to solve for `T2a` on every iteration. One adjustment that I made was to pass only the single equation and not the array of symbolic equations within the loop. In this example I only take the first two real solutions but you can also include the imaginary solutions by adjusting `y` to a 4-column array and passing the whole `Solutions` array to be stored in `y`.

```
sig = 5.670*10^-8;
k = 0.7; 
h = 130; 
p = 0.7;
r1 = 1.50;
r2 = r1 + (1/1000);
r3 = r2 + (100/1000);
T1 = -40 + 273.15;
T3 = 35 + 273.15;

A = 4*pi*r1^2;
e1 = 1-p;
e2 = 1;

syms T2a real
Index = 1;

for x = 40: 150 
   equ2 = (T2a-T3)/(((r3-r2)/((4*pi*r2*r3)*k))+(1/((4*pi*(r3^2))*h))) == (A*sig*((x^4)-(T2a^4)))/((1/e1)+(((1-e2)/e2)*(r1/r2)^2));
   assume(T2a,'real');
   Solutions = double(vpasolve(equ2,T2a)).';
   y(Index,1:2) = [Solutions(1) Solutions(2)];
   Index = Index + 1;
end

x = (40:150);
plot(x,y);
title("Solutions for T2a")
xlabel('x'); ylabel('T2a');
legend('Solution 1','Solution 2');
xlim([40 150]);
```

Comment: No problem, happy to help out!